# Which day of the week do we receive more number of orders without counting actual number of order in particular date in excel?

Tags: excel

[image]

```
Weekday     COUNT_of_weekday_in_orderdate

1   2485    #=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=H7)) formula 
                which I used to calculate count of days(Monday=1,Tuesday=2 
                and so on...)
2   2435
3   2332
4   2314
5   2345
6   2500
7   2387
```

**MAX** 2500
But I don't want to do this stuff and I want direct  value corresponding to max value eg. here is 6 which has 2500.

Row ID  Order Priority  Order Date  Order ID    Cost Price

1   High    1/1/2010    28774   162

2   Not Specified   1/1/2010    88028   178.48

3   Critical    1/2/2010    9285    117.5

4   Low 1/2/2010    37537   1239

5   Low 1/2/2010    37537   3797.19

6   Low 1/2/2010    37537   4656.9

7   Critical    1/2/2010    44069   125.58

8   Critical    1/2/2010    44069   565.8

9   Critical    1/2/2010    89083   39.48

10  Low 1/2/2010    87946   1164.7

11  Critical    1/2/2010    90853   30.94

12  Critical    1/2/2010    90853   144.44

13  High    1/3/2010    7909    118.34

14  Low 1/3/2010    9637    26941.05

15  High    1/3/2010    9762    249.85

16  High    1/3/2010    40354   167.81

17  High    1/3/2010    40354   635.18

18  High    1/3/2010    89583   29.1

19  Low 1/3/2010    87463   120.52

Comment: Do you want the max value itself (question in your text) or the day on which it occurs (question in the title)?

Comment: day on which it occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the max number of orders in a single formula if you're willing to make it more complex with a term for each weekday:

```
=MAX(SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=1)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=2)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=3)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=4)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=5)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=6)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=7)))
```

To get the weekday, the following might work-- it does not work in my Excel 2016 because the array in the second argument isn't recognized but the array functions have been improved in newer versions, so you could try it.

```
=MATCH(
MAX(
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=1)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=2)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=3)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=4)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=5)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=6)),
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=7))
),
{
    SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=1)),
    SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=2)),
    SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=3)),
    SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=4)),
    SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=5)),
    SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=6)),
    SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(ORDERS!C2:C16799,2)=7))
},
0)
```

The first part just determines the max value; the second argument of the `MATCH` function is an array of each of the values by weekday, the MATCH function returns the index of the matching value.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data starts in A1 to to B7, then this will work:

```
=index(A1:A7,match(max(B1:B7),B1:B7,0))
```

max() finds the highest value,
match() finds the position in column B of that value,
Index() takes the daz based on the position.

Comment: weekday and count is not my original data .I use sumproduct formula to get from order table(original data)

Comment: @ShyamjiTiwari Well, you can take the method and expand it to the real data. Should have shown the real data first.

Answer (score 0):

As per you given sample data you can use `SORT()` function if you have ***EXCEL-365***. Try-

```
=@SORT(A1:B6,2,-1)
```

[image]

Comment: weekday and count is not my original data my orginal data is shown in image

Comment: @ShyamjiTiwari Post data as text table so that we can copy paste. Also show you expected output?

Comment: Row ID Order Priority Order Date Order ID Cost Price
1 High 1/1/2010 28774 162
2 Not Specified 1/1/2010 88028 178.48
3 Critical 1/2/2010 9285 117.5
4 Low 1/2/2010 37537 1239
5 Low 1/2/2010 37537 3797.19
6 Low 1/2/2010 37537 4656.9
7 Critical 1/2/2010 44069 125.58
8 Critical 1/2/2010 44069 565.8
9 Critical 1/2/2010 89083 39.48
10 Low 1/2/2010 87946 1164.7
11 Critical 1/2/2010 90853 30.94
12 Critical 1/2/2010 90853 144.44
13 High 1/3/2010 7909 118.34
14 Low 1/3/2010 9637 26941.05
15 High 1/3/2010 9762 249.85
16 High 1/3/2010 40354 167.81